# [Thinkpad X230t]Have to wipe the fingerprint twice to login windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, thinkpad, fingerprint

I have a Thinkpad X230t previously with Windows 7 installed. Later, I upgraded it to Windows 10. Then I come across the problem with the fingerprinter.

Every time I have to wipe my fingerprint twice to login windows 10. It seems to me that the first wiping wakes up the machine and the second boots the operating system.

Is there anyway to fix the problem so that just a single wiping starts the machine and the OS?

Comment: Have you tried to configure the system so it doesn't go to sleep?  Of course, newer fingerprint scanners support Windows Helllo, which is the native fingerprint capability within Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound Is this problem related to the sleeping? Actually, I am using the native fingerprinter. I uninstalled Thinkpad fingerprint driver.